# How to use PEAR behind proxy?

Tags: php, proxy, pear

Initially I used the following with no success;

```
export http_proxy=http://username@password:host:port
```

Worth noting I don't get a connection error directly, instead;

```
[root@pal ~]# sudo pear info  PHP_CodeSniffer-1.2.1
No information found for `PHP_CodeSniffer-1.2.1'
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Instead of using the system's http_proxy, set the proxy directly in pear's config;

```
pear config-set http_proxy http://username:password@yourproxy:80
```

Comment: Attention with special characters in the password like ! or @, we must use html code in hexadecimal, for example the char ! is %21.

Comment: To everyone that tries using `pecl`, `config-set` must be used via: `pear`

Answer (score 18):

You also may have an issue with your sudo user having different configuration from your user for pear.

If you make this :

```
pear config-set http_proxy http://username:password@yourproxy:80
```

Then

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
```

You have change user and the proxy is still not set.

So use the appropriate command:

```
sudo pear config-set http_proxy http://username:password@yourproxy:80
```

*(Issue spotted on Ubuntu 11.04 fresh install)*

Comment: Or run `sudo -E channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com` to preserve environment variables if the proxy is set for the current user.

Answer (score 9):

Note that `pear config-set http_proxy` works whereby `pecl config-set http_proxy` does not, even though `pecl config-get http_proxy` does.

That one cost me me quite a bit of hair pulling :-)

Comment: Could you expound, I think I'm in the same trap.

Answer (score 7):

This will remove proxy settings:

```
pear config-set http_proxy ""
```