# How to install PECL package behind a corporate proxy?

Tags: php, proxy, pear, pecl

I have configure the `pear config-set http_proxy "$http_proxy"`, but this not have any effect.

Take a look below to see what is the output I'm getting:

```
pecl install bz2
WARNING: "pear/bz2" is deprecated in favor of "channel://http://php.net/bzip2/ext/bz2"

Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 101

Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 101

Notice: Undefined variable: proxy_host in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 103

Notice: Undefined variable: proxy_port in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 103

Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 101

Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 101

Notice: Undefined variable: proxy_host in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 103

Notice: Undefined variable: proxy_port in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 103
Could not establish SSL connection through proxy ::
```

Comment: I tried use `openssl.cafile` with `/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`. Again, no effect.

Comment: Relation with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266491/how-to-use-pear-behind-proxy/5939452, but not solve my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use PEAR behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266491/how-to-use-pear-behind-proxy)

Comment: proxy_host looks to be undefined... I would asked questions in comments of the related issue.

Comment: @MarkHan I tried it before, but without success. Thanks.

Comment: which php and pear version are you using?

Comment: Tried with PHP version 7.0.33 and PEAR version 1.10.5.

Comment: I sort of solved it by emptying it since I had that missing var error message conversely with a configured proxy, but it was configured in docker not in the host so it was undesired maybe causing problems - https://askubuntu.com/questions/465198/how-do-i-temporarily-remove-proxy-settings/465199#465199 .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I solved this by adding the below to `php.ini` and all the errors went away.

```
openssl.cafile=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding those lines to the PEAR/Proxy.php file after the line:    stream_context_set_option($fp, 'ssl', 'peer_name', $host );

```
stream_context_set_option($fp, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', False );
stream_context_set_option($fp, 'ssl', 'verify_peer_name', False );
stream_context_set_option($fp, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', True );
```

It's an ugly hack but works for me !